# Installation stops at a black screen on a Dell XPS 15z

Tags: installation, wubi, dell, usb-drive

This is my first time trying to install a Linux distro, and I'm having a bit of a time with it. I've tried to install Ubuntu on my new Dell XPS 15z using the Wubi Windows installer (on x64 Windows 7 Pro) and I've also tried mounting the ISO to a USB drive as explained on ubuntu.com.

Unfortunately, both methods hit the same problem: after some text stuff, the screen turns off. I still have control over things like keyboard brightness, so it's not that the computer's going idle or anything like that. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried [checking the MD5](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the downloaded image to see if it downloaded correctly? Also try using the USB or the disc on another computer to see if it works on that.

Comment: I've tried on two separate dell computers: xps 15 with an integrated graphics card plus nvidia optimus; and an inspiron 14 with onboard intel graphics only; and both worked with 11.04 out of the box. What specs do you have?

Comment: We are on 14.04 but the problem still continues. Selecting second option (noapic) worked for Ubuntu 14.04 code named Trusty.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same laptop but I installed 11.04 (Natty) and everything seems to work except for the touchpad. If you choose this path, you will need to:

1) Add **`acpi=noirq`** to the kernel parameters when you boot up the installation CD. Read the [Boot Parameters](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootParameters). You'd need to press <kbd>F6</kbd> to edit your boot options.

2) The first time you boot into Natty after the installation has completed, you may need to do the same thing again and add 'acpi=noirq' to the kernel parameters. I suggest reading up on how to change the grub configuration to make this kernel parameter permanent for your installation.

3) You may want to get "bumblebee" if you want to have the ability to switch on/off your nvidia GPU or if you have the need to run 3d graphics intensive apps such as games. Go to https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee for more information on this.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is not loading the video driver correctly.

Check if this is a known problem. 10.10 was not really viable on Nvidia - try 9.10 or Natty to see if there is an out-the-box distro that works.