# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 on Dell XPS 12 9Q23 in multi booth mode stops at black scren

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I have been trying this for a number of days now. I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8

I know it works on the XPS 12 (www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FWzqXYc8cc).

I have downloaded the ISO file (ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso).

I have checked the downloaded ISO file integrity using MD5Sum

I have created a live USB (16 GB Make PNY) in Windows8 using PendriveLinux (pendrivelinux.com)

I am not very clear on disk partitions, but I have checked the system drive and it is apparently already divided into different partitions with a primary partition C: where I believe Window8 resides. (Shall I resize the Windows8 C: partition?)

The system BIOS is set with the following relevant Boot parameters:

BIOS Settings (BIOS version A06 product XPS12 9Q23)

Boot:
Add Boot Options: Auto; Windows8 Fast Booth: Disabled; UEFI BOOT: EFI USB1 Path2 (unspecified)
Windows Boot Manager (); Secure Boot: Disabled; Boot List Option:UEFI; Secure Boot Mode: Custom; Fast Boot: Disabled; Load legacy Option Rom: Disabled.

When I attempt the installation I get as far as the GRUB Menu:

Whatever choice I make (Try Ubuntu without installation or Install Ubuntu and the screen goes black.

I can see the USB being accessed, as the led is flashing and I know the system is running in some capacity as the keyboard back-light is on, but without screen image there is very little that I can do.

A similar issues has been raised in this forum:
([Installation stops at a black screen on a Dell XPS 15z](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46519/installation-stops-at-a-black-screen-on-a-dell-xps-15z))
and suggestions are made to add acpi=noirq to the kernel parameters. I am not sure about doing that and what it means, although I am able to access the parameters and in any case they are dealing with a different system.

I am patiently persevering.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I do not know if it would help, but I`m having problems with changing kernel- quite the same as you are describing here. The only version that works properly is 3.5.0-37. Maybe you should try with another version of Ubuntu? I would also recommend using unetbootin for Windows. It has not disappointed me any time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my xps 12 9Q23.
By default the screen luminosity is at 0. 
You have to press Fn+F5 to increase the luminosity to have something on the display.
Or you can plug an external display to see something.